# Using remote server for SP2010

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint 2010 server on remote machine and I want to develop a sharepoint intranet portal on visual studio 2010 which is on my local system.

The problem is that when I try creating a new sharepoint project on my local system, I get this error : "sharepoint server not installed on this computer"

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950548 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951208/

Answer (score 0):

This is a no-can-do if you want to develop ordinary SharePoint projects. One of the requirements of SharePoint is that it is installed on the development machine.

You should start with some training before developing something for SharePoint. Start at SharePoint Dev Center at Msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147.aspx

You can however create integrations through CSOM or OOTB WebServices without having SharePoint installed. But this will require extensive knowledge of SharePoint.

Also, search before posting. This is post is a clear duplicate

Comment: Since it's such a clear duplicate you should vote to close as a duplicate, not post an answer.

Comment: I did vote but there are 49 votes to go

Comment: It takes 5 votes to close the post.  There are currently two.  One is mine.  Given that another user has a possible dup comment only one of the two of you have voted to close.  If it was you who voted to close, then you shouldn't answer it after voting to close; just leave your vote to close and be done.

Comment: Guys its not a duplicate... U say that we need to have sharepoint server locally to develop applications.. Thats not required. We can use remote sharepoint server also. Am getting one error while doing that..  refer this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220047.aspx

Comment: @Priyam, what you are referring to is SharePoint 2013 and the App Model. That is not included in SP2010

Comment: So SP2010 cannot use remote server.?..

Comment: You can but not using the server object model that the default project templates are based upon. You can work remotely with sharepoint through the integration apis or through components like the camelot .net connector http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/, but they are mainly there for creating integrations